# Symfony asset path highlight in PHPStorm after changing web folder name

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

After changing the directory name in Symfony3.4 from `web` to `public_html` the IDE (PHPStorm with Symfony plugin enabled) keeps highlighting all asset paths:

[image: asset highlight]

The website works, all assets are loading fine.

Do I need to change anything to tell the IDE to use the newly renamed folder for assets?

Also edited `composer.json`

```
...
"symfony-web-dir": "public_html",
...
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open PhpStorm Settings.
2. Search for 'Symfony'
3. Select the 'Symfony' node (under 'PHP')
4. Set the `Web Directory` value to `public_html`
5. Keep coding! :)

> NOTICE:
>   This, of course, requires that you have the [IntelliJ Symfony Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) installed and enabled.

Comment: WOW! That took me hours! Thanks.